# mapbox not initializing due to template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, mapbox

I am trying to initialise MapBox but console throw an error 
"Uncaught Error: Container 'map' not found."

I am working with templates which I believed is the issue whereby Mapbox is unable to query the element that is being specified in my html due to some reason. I am fairly new to using template and my context is it fragments the HTML page. Hoping that someone that is experience in it can assist me on this. Thank you!

```js
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'MYAPIKEY';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
        interactive: true,
        dragRotate: true,
        doubleClick: true
        });


        // THIS TRACK'S USER LOCATION IN REAL-TIME USING USER'G GroupSchool
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
        positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        trackUserLocation: true
        }));
        //IF I CHANGE THIS URL TO PHP THAT CONTAINS THE GEOJSON FORMAT
        var url = http://xxxx.geojson;
      


        map.on('load', function () {
            window.setInterval(function() {
                map.getSource('drone').setData(url);
            }, 2000);

            map.addSource('drone',
            {
              type: 'geojson',
              data: url
            });

            map.addLayer({
                "id": "drone",
                "type": "symbol",
                "source": "drone",
                "layout": {
                    "icon-image": "rocket-15"
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
          <template id="home.html">
            <ons-page>
                <!-- Toolbar-->
                <ons-toolbar>
                    <div class="left">
                        <ons-toolbar-button onclick="fn.open()">
                            <ons-icon icon="md-menu"></ons-icon>
                        </ons-toolbar-button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center">
                    </div>
                </ons-toolbar>

                <div id='map' class='container'></div>



            </ons-page>


        </template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the script is running before the `<div id='map' class='container'></div>` has been created. You need to ensure that the Javascript runs *after* the elements are loaded. To do this, you can do one of the following:

1. Move the script to the bottom of your HTML document, right before the `</html>` tag:

   ```
   <html>
       <!-- ALL OF YOUR CURRENT HTML CODE -->
       ...
       <!-- PLACE SCRIPT HERE -->
       <script>
           <!-- ALL OF YOU MAP CODE -->
       </script>
   </html>
   ```
2. Place the script inside a function that is called *after* the document has loaded:

   **Pure Javascript:**

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      // all of your map code here
   }, false);
   ```

   --OR--

   **JQuery:**

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       // all of your map code here
   });
   ```

Comment: I managed to solve it I forgot to initialise the page thanks!

Comment: Or in Vue 3 use: onMounted(() => {
  init();
})

Answer (score 0):

for Angular:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // all of your map code here
}
```

https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit